# Get Time from timestamp in php

Tags: php

I am using `Forecast.io` weather api to get weather data. I have a little problem while i display sunrise and sun set time of that location.

it give time in time-stamp format also provide offset hour difference so i did following code to get time

```
//following GMT value or offset get from api
$offsetHours = '-5 hours';
// This time i get from api
$currentValue = '1401705628'; 
$actualTimeStamp = strtotime($offsetHours,$currentValue);
echo $actualTimeStamp;
echo date('h:i A',$actualTimeStamp);
```

Last echo time is actual time that is '5:40 AM' i got
but in some php version it gives wrong result.

so is there any other way to doing this i cannot update my php version

Comment: What PHP version r u using and in which version it doesn't work ?

Comment: It probably has something to do with your timezone settings... the `date` function uses the default timezone which could be wrong in your case. Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: it works on my local version 5.4  but on clint server that is 5.2 didn't work there. and i cant update that version

Answer (score 0):

```
date('h:i A', (time()-(60*60*5)));
```

Comment: Do not use multiplication where it's not necessary.

Comment: a little explanation would be helpful

Comment: The second parameter of date function requires a timestamp. You can provide the current timestamp - 5 hours (60*60*5)

Comment: huh i tried this but it display wrong time
`date('h:i A', (1401705628-(60*60*5)));`
it shows me 12:40 AM

Comment: Does date('h:i A', time()) provides you with the correct time?
If not the issue could be the timezone.
You can set the correct timezone via date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')
And here's a list of the timezones:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

`gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ('+1 hour'))` you can be as flexible as you like with how many hours you want to go forward or back i.e.(- 1 hour). But have to use strtotime PHP function :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the \DateTime Object of php?
Try something like this:

```
$currentValue = '1401705628';
$offsetHours = '-5 hours';

//Create DateTime Object With Date = NOW()
$date = new \DateTime();

//set Timestamp to DateTime Object
$date->setTimestamp($currentValue);

//Its the date from the timestamp
echo $date->format('h:i A') . '<br><br>';



$pattern = '/^([\+|\-]?)(\d+)\s(hours|hour|minutes|minute)$/iU';
$match = array();

if (preg_match($pattern, $offsetHours, $match)){
    //$match contains an array of matching elements of the pattern
    // $match[0] = '-5 hours'
    // $match[1] = '-'
    // $match[2] = '5'
    // $match[3] = 'hours'

    //Creating the DateInterval String
    $intervalStr = 'PT' . $match[2] . strtoupper(substr($match[3], 0, 1));
    // Create an object of the DateInterval
    $dateInterval = new \DateInterval($intervalStr);

    if ($match[1] === '-'){
        //Substract the DateInterval from Date
        $date->sub($dateInterval);
    }
    else {
        //Add the Dateinterval to date
        $date->add($dateInterval);
    }
} //if preg_match


//Its the date with the offset
echo $date->format('h:i A');
```

**EDIT::** I've updated my example to resolve the time offset dynamically

Comment: not yet but it looks new to me and i will check that. Thanks

Comment: huh i got error as my php version is `PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny16`

Comment: on this line `$date = new \DateTime();`  and this `$dateInterval = new \DateInterval($intervalStr);` am getting error. when i remove `\` didn't show anything

Comment: Seems like your PHP Version didn't support the namespacing. try to remove the backslash before the classnames. Maybe that helps. Otherwise give a comment or try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` at the top of your file after opening the PHP Tag and you may see the error output.